# Set visibility visible but set enable false Android XML Java

Tags: java, android, xml

**I have a button named `HideIt`:**

```
android:id="@+id/HideIt"
android:onClick="HideIt_onClick"
```

**I have another button named `HelloWorld`:**

```
 android:id="@+id/HelloWorld"
 android:onCick="HelloWorld_onClick"
```

**And the third button named `VisibleIt`:**

```
android:id="@+id/VisibleIt"
android:onCick="VisibleIt"
```

***What is the Scenario?***

First of all I click on the `HideIt` button, so it's function will **Invisible** and **Disable** the `HelloWorld` button as codes below:

```
    public void HideIt_onClick(View v) {
    
Button DisableHide = findViewById(R.id.HelloWorld);
DisableHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
DisableHide.setEnabled(false);}
```

Then I click on the `VisibleIt` button, so its function will **Visible** the `HelloWorld` button **BUT** it will **NOT** **Enable** the `HelloWorld` Button as codes below:

```
    public void VisibleIt_onClick(View v) {
        
Button VisibleHelloWorld = findViewById(R.id.HelloWorld);
VisibleHelloWorld.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
```

***What is the problem?***
The problem is when I click on `VisibleI`t, I expect that my `HelloWorld` button set **Visible** but **still disabled**, but it will **never** set visible and it's **still hidden**.

I added a line of code to `VisibleIt` codes to text as below:

```
DisableHide.setEnabled(true);}
```

So `VisibleIt` codes are as below:

```
    public void VisibleIt_onClick(View v) {
        
Button VisibleHelloWorld = findViewById(R.id.HelloWorld);
VisibleHelloWorld.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
DisableHide.setEnabled(true);}
```

In this case when I click on `VisibleIt` Button, it comes **Visible** **BUT** **NOT** **disabled** as **what I wanted**, so I set the `setEnable(false)` in `VisbileIt` codes above, but I had the same problem as before, button `HelloWorld` is **still HIDDEN**.

So I tried a `private void` as codes below but still that problem:

public void VisibleIt_onClick(View v) {

```
Button VisibleHelloWorld = findViewById(R.id.HelloWorld);
VisibleHelloWorld.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
DisableHide.setEnabled(true);
DisableItNow();
}
    private void DisableItNow() {
    Button DisableItPlease = findViewById(R.id.HelloWorld);
    DisableItPlease.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

I need that `HelloWorld` button, which had been **Disabled** and **Gone** by *another Java fuction* , get **visible** by *this fucntion* **BUT** still **disabled**

Comment: Why you keep finding the button for the same id?, you can make it global and access it, maybe that's the cause of problem. Try to initialize the button on onCreate method and access it from anywhere inside the Activity / Fragment

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this below code can help you.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

Button HideIt;
Button HelloWorld;
Button VisibleIt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
   HideIt = findViewById(R.id.HideIt);
   HelloWorld = findViewById(R.id.HelloWorld);
   VisibleIt = findViewById(R.id.VisibleIt);

   HideIt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        HelloWorld.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        HelloWorld.setEnabled(false);
   });
   
   VisibleIt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        HelloWorld.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        HelloWorld.setEnabled(true);
   });

   //in xml code and in Your activity java file you can now safely delete the 
   //function that you created for 
   //hiding or showing
   
  } 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use an if statement inside the `onClick()` to check the visibility as follows:

```
public void VisibleIt_onClick(View v) {
    //Button VisibleHelloWorld = findViewById(R.id.HelloWorld);
    //v is already your button
    if( v.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else if(v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
    else{;/*the view is View.GONE*/}
}
```

so that if the view (your button) is visible it sets the visibility to `View.INVISIBLE` and if is invisible to `View.VISIBLE`. 
For what you are trying to do there is no point in changing the button `.setEnabled()` property.